# Custom NSSortDescriptor to sort Date by date while ignoring time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm implementing a simple CoreData-backed table view that loads objects that I want to be sorted by date. Using a simple descending order date NSSortDescriptor is causing the cells to be sorted and  [grouped by date AND time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO5rC.png). What I want is for the cells to be sorted and [grouped by date but ignoring the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHFkT.png).

I have a workaround that stores two date properties, one has the both time and date and the other only has date. But I do not want to have to maintain two separate properties. i.e. I want date-wise sorting while ignoring the time value while storing only one date property.

Is there any custom NSSortDescriptor that I can write to achieve this behaviour?

Here is my NSManagedObject extension with properties:

```swift
extension AuthenticationKey {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AuthenticationKey> {
        return NSFetchRequest<AuthenticationKey>(entityName: "AuthenticationKey")
    }

    @NSManaged public var createdDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var isFavourite: Bool
    @NSManaged public var key: String
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var createdTime: Date

}
```

This is my NSFetchedResultsController:

```swift
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<AuthenticationKey> = {
    let request = AuthenticationKey.fetchRequest
    request.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(
            keyPath: \AuthenticationKey.createdDate,
            ascending: false
        )
    ]
    return NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: request,
        managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.shared.managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "createdDate",
        cacheName: nil
    )
} ()
```

Currently, `createdDate` stores just the date while `createdTime` stores time and date. I want to be able to have just one date property, i.e. `createdDate` that would have both the date and time, but the sort descriptor would sort only by date and ignore the time.

Here's a sample `AuthenticationKey` object:

```
{
    "id": "6C9570F1-7539-44AC-9ED8-95ADB2CEC846",
    "createdDate": "2019-11-23 00:00:00 +0000",
    "isFavourite": false,
    "key": "oB+peCQ88rSE6dVs14x2X+T0QNwSY4CMrM1fu8WR",
    "name": "Key 298",
    "createdTime": "2019-11-23 12:20:18 +0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is a computed property

```
@objc var startOfDay : Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: theDate)
}
```

and use that as sort condition.

Comment: That results in this error: `Could not extract a String from KeyPath`

Comment: You wrote *sorted by date* so I assumed that you are talking about `Date` instances. I updated the answer.

Comment: Now I understand. The issue is the `sectionNameKeyPath` property. See the updated answer.

Comment: Did you have `@objc` in the very first answer you posted, the one with the `startOfDay` computed property? Because when I first implemented your solution I hadn’t marked `startOfDay` as `@objc` and it seems that’s what caused the key path error I mentioned in my first comment. I did that this time and it fixed the key path error and it worked exactly as I expected it to!

Comment: No, the very first answer was without @objc. I added it when I saw the initialization of the fetch results controller.

Comment: Can you revert to the version with the @objc? That’s the correct answer and I’ll mark it as such.